# C++ IStream interface

Tags: c++

I am new to c++, and I have a task to reverse-engineer a file.
I have got a documentation that explains the file's structure, but the actual file looks totally different, however there was one thing that caught my attention in the document.
It said that the file was a "dump for an IStream interface". What could that mean?
Does this IStream interface use a special kind of encoding, or something like that?
I did my research, I found that the IStream has probably nothing to do with this, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: perhaps this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istream (the tag you used is for `std::istream` which is something different, and tells you nothing about the file structure)

Comment: So is IStream basically a simpler interface to communicate with other types of streams?

Comment: i have no clue, I was just curious because I saw the `istream` tag and that you wrote about `IStream`. I never heard about `IStream` before (I am not working on windows), but the fact that the first hit I found is about some windows stream makes me believe that thats what you are looking for (though I think it is also just a stream, not telling you much about the actual contents of some file)

Comment: you wrote "but the actual file looks totally different". Could you not provide at least partial content of file?

Comment: The content is kinda irrelevant here, I just want to know if IStream changes the raw content when storing it in memory perhabs. There are some readable ascii strings in the file, that I expect to see. To be honest I highly doubt that I got the right documentation, It is probably just a mismatch in versions or something like that.

Comment: "*The content is kinda irrelevant here*" - actually, it is not, since different implementations can store data in different ways. If you want to reverse engineer this properly, you need to identify the format being used for the data. So, it would really be helpful to see both the documentation and the actual data. "*I just want to know if IStream changes the raw content when storing it in memory perhabs* - that is really up to the implementation of the object that is creating the file. `IStream` itself is just an interface, it doesn't define any particular behavior of the data.

Comment: _"IStream itself is just an interface, it doesn't define any particular behavior of the data."_ Okay, thanks! This is the piece of information I wanted to know, so my best guess is just to wait for further instructions. I will ask them about this, but I'm sure that it was just an advice to use an IStream, not an actual useful information. I had concerns before that the documentation was not related to the file, and they said that they have a piece of code, that actually generates these files. Thanks for your help! I will be okay from here :D

Answer (score -1):

```
    You can implement your IStream with your own class using IDL files, something like this
    
    //in IDL:
    [
        object,
        uuid(A416F2AD-68AA-47F4-8276-3E14888AD026),
        dual,
        nonextensible,
        helpstring("IMemoryStream"),
        pointer_default(unique)
    ]
    interface IMemoryStream : IStream
    {
        [id(21), helpstring("method Init")]  HRESULT Init([in] int chunksize);
    };
    
    class ATL_NO_VTABLE MemoryStream :
        public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>
        ,
        public CComCoClass<MemoryStream, &__uuidof(MemoryStream)>,
        public ISupportErrorInfo,
        public IDispatchImpl<IMemoryStream, &__uuidof(IMemoryStream), &LIBID_MemoryStreamLib, 1, 0>
    {
    public:
        MemoryStream();
        ~MemoryStream();
    
        DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_MEMORYSTREAM)
    
        DECLARE_NOT_AGGREGATABLE(MemoryStream)
    
        BEGIN_COM_MAP(MemoryStream)
            COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IStream)
            COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IMemoryStream)
            COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISequentialStream)
            COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISupportErrorInfo)
        END_COM_MAP()
    
        STDMETHOD(Read)(
            /* [annotation] */
            _Out_writes_bytes_to_(cb, *pcbRead)  void* pv,
            /* [annotation][in] */
            _In_  ULONG cb,
            /* [annotation] */
            _Out_opt_  ULONG* pcbRead) override;
    
        STDMETHOD(Write)(
            /* [annotation] */
            _In_reads_bytes_(cb)  const void* pv,
            /* [annotation][in] */
            _In_  ULONG cb,
            /* [annotation] */
            _Out_opt_  ULONG* pcbWritten) override;
    
        STDMETHOD(Seek)(
            /* [in] */ LARGE_INTEGER dlibMove,
            /* [in] */ DWORD dwOrigin,
            /* [annotation] */
            _Out_opt_  ULARGE_INTEGER* plibNewPosition) override;
    
        LONG m_cRef; // Reference count.
        std::vector<unsigned char> m_buffer;
        uint64_t m_buf_position = 0;
        SYSTEMTIME mtime;//last modify time
        SYSTEMTIME atime;//last access time
        SYSTEMTIME ctime;//last change time
    };

STDMETHODIMP MemoryStream::Read(
    /* [annotation] */
    _Out_writes_bytes_to_(cb, *pcbRead)  void* pv,
    /* [annotation][in] */
    _In_  ULONG cb,
    /* [annotation] */
    _Out_opt_  ULONG* pcbRead)
{
    if ((!pv) || (!pcbRead))
        return STG_E_INVALIDPOINTER;

    const bool exceed = cb > (m_buffer.size() - (size_t)m_buf_position);
    if (exceed)
    {
        cb = m_buffer.size() - (size_t)m_buf_position;
    }
    memcpy(pv, &m_buffer[(size_t)m_buf_position], cb);
    *pcbRead = cb;
    m_buf_position += cb;
    GetSystemTime(&atime);
    return exceed ? S_FALSE : S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP MemoryStream::Write(
    /* [annotation] */
    _In_reads_bytes_(cb)  const void* pv,
    /* [annotation][in] */
    _In_  ULONG cb,
    /* [annotation] */
    _Out_opt_  ULONG* pcbWritten)
{
    if (!cb)
    {
        if (pcbWritten)
            *pcbWritten = 0;
        return NOERROR;
    }
    if (!pv)
    {
        if (pcbWritten)
            *pcbWritten = 0;
        return E_POINTER;
    }
    uint64_t newsize = ((uint64_t)cb + m_buf_position);
    if ((newsize < cb) || (newsize < m_buf_position))//overflow
    {
        if (pcbWritten)
            *pcbWritten = 0;
        return STG_E_CANTSAVE;
    }
    if (newsize >= (uint64_t)m_buffer.capacity())
    {
        try {
            m_buffer.reserve((size_t)((newsize >> 63) ? newsize : newsize * 2));//paranoia ??
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            if (pcbWritten)
                *pcbWritten = 0;
            return STG_E_MEDIUMFULL;
        }
    }

    //here: capacity>=newsize, resize does not rellocate, no exception
    if (newsize >= m_buffer.size())
    {
        m_buffer.resize((size_t)newsize);//this does not reallocate
    }
    memcpy(&m_buffer[(size_t)m_buf_position], pv, cb);
    m_buf_position += cb;
    GetSystemTime(&mtime);
    if (pcbWritten)
        *pcbWritten = cb;
    return NOERROR;
}
constexpr uint64_t to_uint64(LARGE_INTEGER l) noexcept
{
    return (((uint64_t)l.HighPart) << 32) || (uint64_t)l.LowPart;
}

constexpr int64_t to_int64(LARGE_INTEGER l) noexcept
{
    return (((int64_t)l.HighPart) << 32) || (int64_t)l.LowPart;
};
constexpr size_t to_size_t(ULARGE_INTEGER l) noexcept
{
    return (sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(l.LowPart)) ? (size_t)l.LowPart : (size_t)l.QuadPart;
};
constexpr ULARGE_INTEGER toULARGE(size_t val) noexcept
{
    ULARGE_INTEGER out{};
    out.LowPart = val & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    if (sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(ULARGE_INTEGER))
        out.HighPart = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)val) >> 32);
    return out;
}
STDMETHODIMP MemoryStream::Seek(
    /* [in] */ LARGE_INTEGER dlibMove,
    /* [in] */ DWORD dwOrigin,
    /* [annotation] */
    _Out_opt_  ULARGE_INTEGER* plibNewPosition)
{

    uint64_t newpos = to_uint64(dlibMove);
    if (dwOrigin == STREAM_SEEK_CUR)
    {
        if (dlibMove.HighPart < 0)
            return STG_E_INVALIDFUNCTION;
        newpos += m_buf_position;
    }
    else
        if (dwOrigin == STREAM_SEEK_END)
        {
            if (dlibMove.HighPart < 0)
                newpos = m_buffer.size() + to_int64(dlibMove);
            else
                newpos += m_buffer.size();
        }
        else
            if (dwOrigin != STREAM_SEEK_SET)
                return  STG_E_INVALIDFUNCTION;

    if (newpos < m_buf_position)//could be overflow if  STREAM_SEEK_CUR, STREAM_SEEK_END
        return STG_E_INVALIDFUNCTION;

    if (newpos >= m_buffer.capacity())
    {
        try {
            m_buffer.reserve((size_t)(newpos * 2));
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            return STG_E_MEDIUMFULL;
        }
    }
    if (newpos >= m_buffer.size())
        m_buffer.resize((size_t)newpos);
    m_buf_position = newpos;//main
    if (plibNewPosition)
    {
        plibNewPosition->HighPart = newpos >> 32;
        plibNewPosition->LowPart = (newpos & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    return S_OK;

}
```